# Can you make Golang drop packets on writes rather than block?

Tags: go

Given a channel of length N, I want to write to it only if it is not full. Else I will drop this packet and process the next one.

Is this possible in GOlang

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use `select`. Example:

```
package main

func main() {

    ch := make(chan int, 2)

    for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
        select {
        case ch <- i:
            // process this packet
            println(i)
        default:
            println("full")
            // skip the packet and continue
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A bit after the fact I know, but this is exactly what is implemented by the `OverflowingChannel` type in the helper package I wrote. It effectively uses the select trick above.

- Code: https://github.com/eapache/channels
- Documentation: https://godoc.org/github.com/eapache/channels